# Python pandas load and read file

Tags: python, pandas

i just started python, how to read this and what it mean?

```
col_desc = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/zenius/Home-Credit/HomeCredit_columns_description.csv', encoding='Latin-1')
col_desc[col_desc['Table'] == "application_{train|test}.csv"]
```

I've been looking for it but haven't found it

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: If you're a Python beginner I strongly recommend that you don't go anywhere near *pandas* until you've learned some fundmentals

Comment: You should ask a specific question. If you don't understand something, try to look it up yourself first, before asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you create the DataFrame (which is an object) and asign to a variable called "col_desc"

The second line is an statement that should output the row where in the column named "Table" the value is equal to "application_{train|test}.csv".

May be the confusion is that you are trying to access the "application_{train|test}.csv" file but before you must initializate the DataFrame.